# I have to add subview in forloop . But its not working

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

When i compile `DispatchQueue.main.async` it recieve following error

> break   T (code=1, subcode=0x105448b08)
> When i need to update UI it cause error and not update UI

```
@IBAction func buRecord(_ sender: Any) {
    self.progressView.isHidden = true
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])
    let overlayArrow: UIImageView = {
        let overlayArrow = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 20, y: self.view.center.y, width: (self.view.bounds.width) - 40, height: 80))
        overlayArrow.image = UIImage(named: "LR")
        overlayArrow.tag = 1
        return overlayArrow
        
    }()
    let overlayUN: UIImageView = {
        
        let overlayUN = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.init(x: (self.view.center.x) - 50, y: 100, width:80, height: (self.view.bounds.height) - 230))
        overlayUN.image = UIImage(named: "UD")
        overlayUN.tag = 2
        return overlayUN
        
    }()
    var v = 1
    var v2 = 1
    for   count in ( 1 ..< 13) {
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        sleep(2)
        if  count <= 5{
           
                self.mainTextLabel.text = "Move your Head Up and Down"
                self.counterLabel.text = String(count)
            print("\(count) seconds to the up and down")
            self.mainView.addSubview(overlayUN)
            
        }else if count <= 10{
            print("\(v) seconds to the LR")
            self.counterLabel.text = String(v)
            v += 1
            
        }else if  count <= 12{
            print("\(v2) seconds to the Smile")
            self.counterLabel.text = String(v2)
            v2 += 1
            
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show complete code context and error message

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: Any error message in console when this happens?

Comment: no error on console Just metal api validation is appearing
2020-12-11 14:54:04.057755+0500 KNWN[3545:1323864] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2020-12-11 14:54:04.058090+0500 KNWN[3545:1323864] Metal API Validation Enabled
(lldb)